# Error Cannot open database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, web-config

I use asp.net 4 and c#. I'm testing a website on my local computer.

Her my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CmsConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=CmsSiteNameExtension; Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
    <add name="CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel" connectionString="Metadata=res://*/;          provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;&#xA;          Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CmsSiteNameExtension;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I receive this error when try to run locally my web app.

```
Cannot open database "CmsSiteNameExtension" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'WIN-S6G3M6TMQLT\XXX'
```

Any idea what is wrong and how to solve it?

STACK:

```
    [SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "CmsSiteNameExtension" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'WIN-S6G3M6TMQLT\XXX'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5009598
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +183
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +239
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +52

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +161
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +98
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +81
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +46
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +44
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +184
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +41
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +59
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +150
   System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +300
   WebProject.Web.Cms.FrontEndCms.CommonUIComponents.HtmlHeadMain.IncludeHtmlCodeHeader() in C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\SVN-Working-ORIGINAL\WebProject\Src\WebProject.Web\Cms\FrontEndCms\Components\Generals\HtmlHeadMain.ascx.cs:28
   WebProject.Web.Cms.FrontEndCms.CommonUIComponents.HtmlHeadMain.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\SVN-Working-ORIGINAL\WebProject\Src\WebProject.Web\Cms\FrontEndCms\Components\Generals\HtmlHeadMain.ascx.cs:19
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the database with SQL Management Studio using the same user with Windows Authentication?

Comment: yes using SQL Management Studio with the same User (posted in the error) with Windows Authentication is working... any ideas? thanks

Comment: are you sure it's windows and not sql authentication? Because if I try with SQL Management studio I cannot specify another user than logged user (me) when selecting Windows Authentication.

Comment: yes correct actually I cannot select another User. I have the User (me) automatically selected when using Windows Authentication. What you see in the error is (me) the default user when connecting with SQL Management studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Integrated Security=True ( replace Integrated Security=SSPI with Integrated Security=True), i hope it will work.

Comment: i think this won't help, it should be the same.